# Is there a way to silence/stop particular sound effects, especially on the main screen?

Tags: team-fortress-2

The applause from the Saxxy Awards on the main screen is driving me insane. I don't want to turn my entire sound off for it, though.

Is there a way to disable specific sounds, especially those on the main/home screen?

Comment: Heavy Weapons Guy, please have my babies.

Comment: This has been now removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the console (must be enabled in Keyboard Advanced Options- default key: '~').

Enter this:

```
sv_cheats 1
stopsound
```

(You can bind this to a key with something like `bind KP_ADD "sv_cheats 1; stopsound"`.)

Alternately, you can override the Saxxy sound resources with [silent ones](http://www.reddit.com/r/tf2/comments/h61nr/tf/c1sv935).